# Select into with substring and orderby

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to pass a string from a substring of a database column into a variable.

Originally I did this before I realised that this could return more than one row. In the case of this returning more than I row I need to make sure I only return the most recent value (the most recent date).

```
SELECT SUBSTR (
                       description
                      ,1
                      ,  INSTR (
                             description
                            ,' ' )
                       - 1 )
            INTO   v_value
            FROM   sdok s
            WHERE  s.type = 2
            AND    s.case_no = in_object.case_no;
```

Which is why I attempted this:

```
SELECT *
        FROM   (SELECT   SUBSTR (
                             description
                            ,1
                            ,  INSTR (
                                   description
                                  ,' ' )
                             - 1 )
                        ,s.case_no
                        ,s.date
                FROM     sdok s
                WHERE    s.type = 2
                AND      NVL ( s.deleted, 'N' ) <> 'J'
                ORDER BY s.date)
        WHERE  ROWNUM = 1
        AND    s.case_no = in_object.case_no;
```

This returns 3 columns of data, which enables me to check I have the right case and date, but I still only really need the value from column 1 (the substring) to pass into my variable. I tried putting INTO after the SUBSTR, but before the call to s.case_no and s.date, but that doesn't work. Yet I need to do the date comparison (to get the most recent date) and get the right case_no, before I can get the first row. I'm guessing there is another way to compare the case_no and order by date, so that I only return the value of the substring?

Help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I understood the question:

```
SELECT x.a_substring
  INTO local_variable
  FROM   (SELECT   SUBSTR (description
                            ,1
                            ,INSTR (description, ' ' ) - 1 
                          ) a_substring
                         --
                        ,s.case_no
                        ,s.date
                FROM     sdok s
                WHERE    s.type = 2
                  AND    NVL ( s.deleted, 'N' ) <> 'J'
                  AND    s.case_no = 'xxxxxxxxx'
                ORDER BY s.date
               ) x
        WHERE  ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! Wasn't that far off, but wow, I spent way too long trying to do that last finish.

Answer (score 1):

You can do much easier using "first first 1 rows only" or aggregate function max(str)keep(dense_rank first order by s.date):

```
 SELECT   
          SUBSTR (description
             ,1
             ,INSTR (description, ' ' ) - 1 
           ) a_substring INTO local_variable
 FROM     sdok s
 WHERE    s.type = 2
   AND    NVL ( s.deleted, 'N' ) <> 'J'
   AND    s.case_no = 'xxxxxxxxx'
 ORDER BY s.date
 fetch first 1 rows only
/
 SELECT max(  
          SUBSTR (description
             ,1
             ,INSTR (description, ' ' ) - 1 
           )
        )keep(dense_rank first order by s.date) a_substring
        INTO local_variable
 FROM     sdok s
 WHERE    s.type = 2
   AND    NVL ( s.deleted, 'N' ) <> 'J'
   AND    s.case_no = 'xxxxxxxxx'
/
```